# How to set an Alarm or Reminder events in Windows 8?

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

Do we have a functionality in Windows 8 where I can set an Alarm or a Reminder (with recurrence!!) and forget about it (and the OS will do the rest)? Or do I need to create a background task to do the work?

It is not hard to schedule one event but I would not want to schedule a whole set of recurrence events.

The calendar is already doing it, can I tie into this mechanism?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Scheduled Notifications](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jimoneil/archive/2012/08/08/windows-8-notifications-scheduled-notifications.aspx) but there's a limit of 4096 of those, so the recommendation for a recurring task would be to use a [MaintenanceTrigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.background.maintenancetrigger.maintenancetrigger.aspx).  A couple of things to be aware of:

- A maintenance trigger will NOT fire if on battery power, but the
  notifications are buffered so when you're plugged in again you'll
  receive them.
- There's up to a 15 minute window from the [freshnessTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.background.maintenancetrigger.freshnesstime.aspx#Y0) in terms
  of the actual notification being triggered, so keep that in mind in
  terms of scheduling.  For instance, if you set a notification to
  occur at noon, it might not hit until 12:14:59.