# Do we have Reminders in windows 8

Tags: windows-8, windows-store-apps

I want to add reminders in my application and the user should have facility to ON/OFF the reminders. I did it in windows phone, but I can't find the Reminder class in windows 8.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/q/12731994/2065121

Answer (score 2):

We have toast notifications in Windows 8 apps, which can be used as reminders (a rectangular pop-up that will appear in the upper right-hand corner of your machine, no matter what program you are currently using).  More info at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh761493.aspx (also see the topics below this for how-to info).

The end user has the ability to turn off notifications globally (from all apps) or just from a single app.

Comment: With toast notifiacation user don't have snoozing option ryt?
and i want to set this reminder with daily,weekly,monthly,never options.

Comment: No, no snoozing option.  The built-in functionality is that when you click the toast notification, it launches the app that created it.  You can schedule notifications at varying time lengths (daily, monthly, etc.) as you say; there is documentation on how to schedule one at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465417.aspx.